# Command to sum values in a list

Tags: macros, expl3

I'm a novice to `expl3`. Can something list this be done?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\sumlist}{m}{
    \clist_add:n { #1 }
}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}
    \sumlist{1,2} % should output 3
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's essentially a one-liner. With `\clist_use:nn` we can put `+` between any two items and `\int_eval:n` fully expands its argument in order to do the computation. Note that `1+-4` is accepted and returns `-3`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\listadd}{m}
 {
  \int_eval:n { \clist_use:nn {#1} { + } }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\listadd{1,2}

\listadd{1,-4,3}

\edef\test{\listadd{-3,2*3,-4}}
\texttt{\meaning\test}

\end{document}
```

[image]

With `\fp_eval:n` you can also sum floating point numbers.

**Note.** See edit history for the previous version of 2021.

Comment: According to the documentation, `\clist_use:nn` is new since 2021-05-10 so was not available at the time but I think that today, `\clist_map_function:nN {#1} \mjc_listadd:n` can be replaced by `\clist_use:nn {#1} { + }` and then `\cs_new:Nn \mjc_listadd:n { + #1 }` can be removed (also `\usepackage{xfp}`).

Comment: @matexmatics You're right on all accounts. Edited accordingly.

Answer (score 4):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\sumlist}{m}{
    \int_zero:N\l_tmpa_int
    \clist_map_inline:nn{#1} { \int_add:Nn\l_tmpa_int{##1} }
    \int_use:N\l_tmpa_int
}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}
    \sumlist{1,2} % should output 3
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

For completeness, a fully expandable approach using LaTeX2e:

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand\sumlist[1]{\the\numexpr\sumlistaux#1,\relax\relax}
\def\sumlistaux#1,#2\relax{#1\ifx\relax#2\else+\sumlistaux#2\relax\fi}
\begin{document}
\sumlist{1,2} % should output 3

\sumlist{1,1,2,3,5}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Also for completeness, a one-liner with LuaLaTeX:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\newcommand\sumlist[1]{\directlua{tex.sprint(load("return "..table.concat({#1},'+'))())}}
\begin{document}
\sumlist{1,4,7,8,3}
\end{document}
```

[image]